# Enabling And Disabling Textboxes through Radiobuttons in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, if-statement

i have this form "Emp_Employee"
where i have 4 radiobuttons: radio_ID, radio_ ... 
and 4 text boxes: id,name,salary,desgination
when i load my form all the textboxes are disabled initially (which is fine) but when i check any radiobutton to enable it's relative textbox it arnt happening.. all textboxes remains disabled till the end no matter which radiobox is checked!
Kindly Help..

```
private void Emp_Employee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    id.Enabled = false;
    name.Enabled = false;
    salary.Enabled = false;
    designation.Enabled = false;

    if (radio_ID.Checked == true)
    {
        id.Enabled = true;
        name.Enabled = false;
        salary.Enabled = false;
        designation.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (radio_Name.Checked == true)
    {
        name.Enabled = true;
        id.Enabled = false;
        salary.Enabled = false;
        designation.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (radio_Salary.Checked == true)
    {
        salary.Enabled = true;
        id.Enabled = false;
        name.Enabled = false;
        designation.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (radio_Designation.Checked == true)
    {
        designation.Enabled = true;
        id.Enabled = false;
        name.Enabled = false;
        salary.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the UI toolkit you are using as a tag. I guess it is WinForms.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to check whether your code executes at all when you think it does?

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe all radiobuttons to same `CheckedChanged` event handler and then just assign radiobutton's `Checked` state to `Enabled` state of textboxes:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    id.Enabled = radio_ID.Checked;
    name.Enabled = radio_Name.Checked;
    salary.Enabled = radio_Salary.Checked;
    designation.Enabled = radio_Designation.Checked;
}
```

Another cool option is usage of databinding. You can simply bind these two properties on form load:

```
private void Emp_Employee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    id.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", radio_ID, "Checked");
    name.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", radio_Name, "Checked");
    salary.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", radio_Salary, "Checked");
    designation.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", radio_Designation, "Checked");
}
```

Thus you even don't need to handle radiobutton's `CheckedChanged` event - textboxes will reflect state of radiobuttons automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
Page_Load event wont trigger the desired results.
```

You need to add another event in order to enable the textbox data.
For example:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, 
                                         EventArgs e)
{
      salary.Enabled = true;
      id.Enabled = false;
      name.Enabled = false;
      designation.Enabled = false;
}
```

Refer [this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try your text box enabling and disabling in radio button Checked changed event

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rb_CheckedChanged);


void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you do your text box enabling and disableing operation here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you're using WinForms, not Wpf*

Your entire code is residing inside the `Form.Load` event which is executing only once per Form load. you need to move the update code to a code that is executing when each `RadioButton` is checked. Usually a `RadioButton.CheckedChanged` event.

Answer (score -1):

if you use xaml , No need to code C#

Try this

```
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton0" GroupName="RadioButtonGroup1"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" GroupName="RadioButtonGroup1"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton2" GroupName="RadioButtonGroup1"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton3" GroupName="RadioButtonGroup1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton0}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton1}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton2}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton3}"/>
```

Comment: I don't think WPF has forms

Answer (score -2):

I think you can change the Visibility:

textBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

I hope it works, it written from my mind.